# Stalling Jasmine Tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, gruntjs

I'm working on a large, thick client, javascript project that uses jasmine for testing.  In the most recent build when I try running jasmine via phantom it just hangs.  Either it's going incredibly slowly or it's just stuck.

When I try going back through older commits to see if it's an issue it's pretty consistently a problem, but once I think I've come across a commit where it works quickly all of the time, I run it again and it stalls.

I'm running a Mac OS X 10.6 and the same problem is happening on colleague's machine which is a Windows XP machine.  I'm running grunt v0.3.17.  Some other people on the team are having no problem running the tests on their machines with the same version of the code and the same version of Grunt.

This is a true mystery.  Thoughts?

Comment: I see the same thing with chrome. Random hangs that are resolved when I delete a bunch of tests. Binary searching to a file doesn't yield a conclusive result. The failure is somewhat random.

Comment: Are you using any environment variables when running tests that you might have forgotten?